# How can I route a secure socket connection to different destination servers via a proxy?

Tags: proxy, tcp, socket, socks

My task is to address different servers via secure socket connections at the destination.

But the problem is that you can not specify different target servers over normal socket connections. Also, there is no way, as with HTTP(S) via header, to provide additional information.

I thought of a SOCKS5 server at the destination, which can then address the destination servers. The proxy server could be NGINX, if it supports SOCKS5.

[See my example diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBczF.png)

Usually such a proxy lies with the client. Theoretically, it should also work if the SOCKS5 proxy is located at the receiver in the target network.

Can this work or are there other solutions? If possible without programming. Only with configuration.

Comment: Use TLS SNI for hostname?

Comment: Are you trying to load-balance?

Comment: @MTG No load-balance. The devices behind are smart devices, which are controlled over own comands over TCP/socket.

Comment: @Tero Kilkanen I will take a look into TLS SNI. I think the Dante server can do what I want. I have to try.